# Solidity function return problem

Tags: solidity, web3js

I feel frustrated when I was reading the documentation of function `returns`. If function return multiple values. How to get the correct return from calling the function in frontend? When I see the response, it is an array like stuff, with the type that I define in side the function return.

I am using `web3` & `web-vitals` npm package for my frontend. It will be nice if some examples can be provided. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Treat the returned value as objects. Check this web3js code. The called contract function returns multiple data as objects.

```
async function getSiteStats() {
    let rawResult = await contract.methods.getSiteStats().call();
 
    let retrieved = {
        totalInvested: web3.utils.fromWei(rawResult[0]), 
        totalDeposits: parseInt(rawResult[1]),
        contractBalance: web3.utils.fromWei(rawResult[2]),
        contractPercent: (parseInt(rawResult[3]) / _PERCENTS_DIVIDER*100)
        }

    return retrieved;
}
```